# How to assign properties to a MovieClip in Flash and have them accessible in Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, components, ria

### Situation / Question

Here's the situation.

In Flash Professional, I have a MovieClip and that clip has children.  Let's say the parent clip is a night sky and the children are different instances of a star MovieClip that animates in a loop.  This whole thing compiles down to a NightSky.swc which I use in Flash Builder as part of a larger project.

In Flash Pro, I position the child clips with a high level of precision.  From there, I want to assign properties to these "stars."  Say, I want to assign "galaxyId" and "isRedGiant" but (***and this is key***) I want to edit those properties in Flash Professional and have those value accessible in Flex.  How do I do that?

### Example

For example, using Flash Pro, I place 6 stars in the sky, give them all a galaxy ID of "MilkyWay" and designate 3 of them to be red giants.  Then, I compile the SWC and move over to flex.  In Flex (Flash Builder), I have some logic along the lines of:

```
public function showRedPulse():void {
    //psuedo-code just as an example:
    for each Child in the Night Sky
       if Child is in the Milky Way
           and if Child is a Red Giant
               Then, gotoAndPlay("redPulse")
}
```

***So basically, I need to access the properties in Flex, but I need to set them in Flash.***

### Previous Solution

Ok. So I've done this for about 2 years now in CS4 but, in CS5, it's ***very*** buggy. So I'm looking for a new approach.  What I did before was create an ActionScript Class (extending UIMovieClip) and add the Inspectable metatag to the fields I needed to see in Flash like this:

```
private var _galaxyId:String;

[Inspectable(name="galaxyId", type=String, defaultValue="MilkyWay")]
public function set galaxyId(value:String):void {
     _galaxyId = value;
}
```

Then, in flash professional, I would have the "star" use the actionscript class as it's base class.  Then, I would right click on the star in the library and edit it's component definition, pointing it to the same class.  Once I did that, all the inspectable properties would show up in Flash's Component Inspector.

### Summary

My previous approach worked beautifully, for years. Now, in CS5, it's extremely buggy, working only sometimes! I'm completely stuck, can't move forward on my project, and I'm thinking of abandoning Flash Pro, entirely and trying Flash Catalyst, instead.

***I just need to create Objects in Flash that I can use in Flex (3.6 not Flex 4).  I need those Flash Objects to have properties that I can edit in Flash and access in Flex code.***

How else can I approach this? This shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: There is no Flex 3.6 yet, is there?  3.5 is the latest "Gold" release.

Comment: Have you tried adding a frame action in frame1 of your MovieClips and setting the variable values there?  You could omit the metatags and just create plain public setters and getters.

Comment: @Flextras: I sure hope there's a 3.6, we've been using for about 14 months. lol (If I remember correctly, some of our code also doesn't work under 3.5)  The latest version is 3.6.0.16736 and it comes from the nightly builds. So I guess the official answer is "yes and no."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there's a subtle bug in CS5 related to using components.

```
Flash CS5 + components as children in UIMovieClips = fail.
```

The exact same file when saved as a CS4 file works with zero modifications.

So the "answer" to this question is that the previous solution is the right way to do it.  It just might take some time for this odd bug to get ironed out in CS5.  As far as I know, Adobe is aware of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the symbol properties, create a new class for the movieclip, then declare your property there.  As long as you're importing the swc, Flex will see the property and be type-safe.

There isn't much good documentation out there, this is the best I could find:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_base_class.html

Comment: I found out there's a bug in CS5. I'll try your solution when I get a chance as a possible workaround...